# Thumbnail Image is posted in facebook using (/me/feed) facebook graph api

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

This is the code I am using for posting Image on Wall.

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/" 
  + Login.facebookid 
  + "/feed?access_token=" + accesstoken 
  + "&method=post" 
  + "&message=" + strFullMessage.replaceAll(" ", "%20") 
  + "&picture=" + imageUrl 
  + "&privacy=" + resp
```

I am using facebook Graph API to post image on wall.

What I expected is Image will post in exact size as the Image has?

But the image is posted in Thumbnail size.

Why the graph api is taking thumbnail image?

But when I use (`/me/photos`),it is taking full image.Why this change in API.

How to post full image using (`/me/feed`)? Is this a bug in facebook Graph API?

Answer (score 3):

If you post to the me/feed endpoint you will get a thumbnail, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

Use the me/photos if you want a full image posted.

Comment: But,if you see my post I also added privacy so that only selected members can see the post.I tried with (/me/photos)but getting Bad request as response. Why the facebook is not allowing to post full Image on wall? Is this a bug from Facebook api?

Comment: You can't get a full image with me/feed and this is not a bug, this is by design. Another approach is to use Open Graph - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/distribution/#image if you don't want to use me/photos.

Comment: If I use me/photos,I am getting Bad Request as Response

Answer (score 1):

This method is used to share a Link on facebook user's feed(wall).

You can't post full image using me/feed, It will always post it as a link.
You can use me/photos for putting big photos.

```
FB.api('me/photos', 'post',
    { 
    url:'MY_URL',
    href:'MY_LINK,
    message: 'photo description',                
    access_token:accessToken
    },
    function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (!response || response.error) {
            alert('Error occurred');
        } else {
            alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
        }
});
```

Above is the method to do it with me/photos.

If this helped you, consider accepting my answer.